# Let $X$ be a nonzero $n × n$ matrix such that $X^m = 0$ for some $m ∈ N$. Let $b ∈ N$ be the smallest number for which $X^b = 0$. Show that $b≤ n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, minimal-polynomials

I figure it has something to do with minimal polynomials and the Jordan canonical form, I just can't piece it together. I would really appreciate a hint on how to start it.

Answer (score 2):

If the range of $X^k$ is equal to the range of $X^{k+1}$ then the range of $X^{k+i}$ is equal to the range of $X^k$ for all positive $k$.

It follows the ranks of $X,X^2,\dots,X^b$ are strictly decreasing, and since the rank of $X$ is at most $n$ we have $b$ is at most $n$.

Comment: Excellent! I thought this was much deeper, using Cayley-Hamilton to bound the degree of the minimal polynomial...

Comment: I think Cayley Hamilton uses something similar  in one of the parts of the proof with $(X-\lambda I)^k$ on some of the subspaces but I don't remember very well.

Answer (score 0):

Your hunch is correct: The minimal polynomial must be divide $t^m$ and have degree at most $n$.